# Get taxonomy terms value in views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types

1. Program
2. Registration

and one taxonomy

1. Program type

Program content type having term reference with program type taxonomy
and registration having node reference with a program.

I am using views to list out all registrations.

How can I get the program type terms value in registration content type list?

Comment: Might I suggest an alternative approach using entity reference instead of term reference and node reference? That is if you can delete these fields and use the new one's to refer those entities.

Comment: Ok I changed it to entity reference but how to get the terms value?

Answer (score 1):

Considering entity reference fields in the following manner:

1. Program having an entity reference field pointing to the terms of program type vocabulary.
2. Registration having an entity reference field pointing to nodes of type Program.

To achieve what you want:

1. Create a view of content. Of type "Registration". Add required fields from registration content type
2. Add a relationship of type "Entity reference: referring entity" with field from #2 above.
3. This will enable you to add attributes/fields from the "Program" content type.
4. Add a relationship of "Entity reference: referring entity" with the field from #1 above (pointing to terms). **Important:** Use the earlier relationship in this new relationship (i.e. nested relationship).
5. This will let you add attributes/fields from the taxonomy terms.